# Why doesn't Rust demand dereferencing in some cases?

Tags: rust

When I see this code everything is clear. We have a reference that we should dereference to manipulate and read data inside of it.

```
fn twice(x: &mut u8) {   
    *x = *x * 2;
}
```

But why does the following code compile?

```
fn twice(x: &u8) -> u8 {
    x * 2
}
```

Why doesn't Rust demand from me to dereference `x` here and requires it in the first example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rust has a [`Mul<u8>` implementation for `&u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#impl-Mul%3Cu8%3E-1). This means that you can multiply an `&u8` and `u8` to get a `u8`, with no dereferencing needed. However, for whatever reason, there's no instance for `&mut u8`, so the following will fail:

```rust
fn twice(x: &mut u8) -> u8 {
    x * 2
}
```